# Navigation component -navigation drawer menu not working

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack, android-navigation-graph

I am using the navigation component with navgraph and navigation drawer.

I have 3 fragments `A` (startDestination) , `B` and `C`.

I have a navigation drawer with menus `a`,`b`,`c` for the three fragments.

Now I have a button in `A` fragment to navigate directly to `C` fragment (i.e without using side drawer). When I am in Fragment `C` (navigated via the button) I am unable to tap on the menu `a` for Fragment `A`. I cant understand where is the problem. Only navigating through the navigation drawer works fine.